# Linear transformations such that $A^3=I$ but $A^2\neq I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Do any such linear transformations exist? I'm new to linear algebra. Whenever I'm confronted with problems like these I tend to just guess and hope to get lucky. How would you go about constructing such a transformation?

And, to generalize, how would you construct a linear transformation such that $A^j=I$ but $A^{j-1}$ (or any smaller degree greater than one)$\neq I$?

Comment: Consider rotating a plane by $120^\circ$.

Comment: Do you know about rotation matrices? Permutation matrices?  Eigenvalues?

Comment: First try numbers. Is there some $z$ such that $z^2 \neq 1$ but $z^3 = 1$?

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered. Yes @omnomnomnom I studied those very recently. As soon as I saw the answers I realized I should've given it a bit more thought. And if I'd just thought about roots of unity, that would've helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Take the vector space generated by the base $\{e_1, e_2,e_3\}$ and define $A(e_1)=e_2$, $A(e_2)=e_3$ and $A(e_3)=e_1$.

Same idea for generalization.

Answer (score 2):

Try the linear transformation given by the following matrix:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{j}\right)&-\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{j}\right)\\
\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{j}\right)&\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{j}\right)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This corresponds with (counterclockwise) rotation over an angle of $\frac{2\pi}{j}$ in 2 dimensions. Now $A^j=I$ but $A^k\neq I$ for all $1\leq k \leq j-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial $\;x^3-1\;$ , for which this is the *minimal polynomial*:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

An idea in $\mathbb{R}^n$: the rotation of angle $\frac{2\pi}{j}$ along an axis